# FFMPEG: Generated video will not concat with the rest

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to make a video with FFMPEG, and I am concat'ing several videos together. However, the last two are generated from a PNG image using the `-loop` option.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img001.png -filter crop=768:432:128:72 -c:v libxvid -q 1 -t 5 -s 360x288 -aspect 16:9 out1.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img002.png -filter crop=768:432:128:72 -c:v libxvid -q 1 -t 5 -s 360x288 -aspect 16:9 out2.mp4
```

Then I add silence to it using a wav file.

```
ffmpeg -i out1.mp4 -i silence.wav -shortest -c:v copy -c:a ac3 out11.mp4
ffmpeg -i out2.mp4 -i silence.wav -shortest -c:v copy -c:a ac3 out21.mp4
```

After that I expect that it is ready, so I run the concat filter.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i full.txt -c copy "Q1-Full.mp4"
```

`full.txt` contains

```
file 'Likoonl-Q1-Intro.mp4'
file 'Likoonl-Q1-All.mp4'
file 'Likoonl-Q1-X2.mp4'
file 'out11.mp4'
file 'out21.mp4'
```

And right at the end of the run, I get this output.

```
[mp4 @ 049e6a80] st:0 PTS: 98240188 DTS: 98240188 < 689858768 invalid, clipping
```

When I play `Q1-Full.mp4`, it has the correct duration, but stops playing at the end of 'Likoonl-Q1-X2.mp4'.

Comment: Please provide the **full, uncut** console output of your ffmpeg commands. Either in the post or with Pastebin. How did you generate the first three files?

Comment: The first 3 files are generated in another program called Handbrake.

Comment: Then I would assume that they use different encoding settings than the two you generate. What did you set in Handbrake? Perhaps you can show us the output of `ffmpeg -i Likoonl-Q1-Intro.mp4`? Note that when you do a `-c copy` and concatenate files of different origin, problems are quite expected. It could be possible to re-encode and/or throw away the original timestamps…

Comment: I ended up using the concat with a complex filtergraph. I guess it's a filter. Will add an answer.

Comment: Would still be good to see the info about your files, in addition to having an answer on how you fixed it.

Comment: I think that you should use filter setpts=STARTPTS-PTS when you encode video and asetpts=STARTPTS-PTS when you encode audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i Q1-Full.mp4 -i Q1-Contact.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"
```